# Error saving to MBR

Tags: grub2, permissions, bootloader

I get the following error when I try and save to MBR in Grub Customizer.

[image]

It used to work OK, it there something I need to do to make changes to the Grub Menu stick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it!

Start Terminal and load your file browser (I use Dolphin) with the following command

```
sudo dolphin /usr/sbin/
```

Navigate to the file grub-bios-setup, right click on the file name and select permissions. Make sure that the file has the correct permissions:

[image]

All done